# How to reverse the gradient and ticks in BarLegend

Tags: plotting, legending

I created a plot with a horizontal BarLegend for TemperatureColors (see[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0d9Jk.jpg)).

Code:

```
PlotLegends -> 
     Placed[BarLegend[{"TemperatureMap", {15, 30}},Ticks -> Table[i, {i, 15, 31, 1}], LegendMarkerSize -> 300, 
       LegendLabel -> "T(\[Degree]C)", 
       LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black, 11}], {Bottom, Center}]
```

Now I just want to have the BarLegend having the temperatures on it decreasing from left to right, means values and colors reversed with high temperatures on the left.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[BarLegend[{ColorData["TemperatureMap"][1 - #] &, {15, 30}}, 
    LegendMarkerSize -> 300, LegendLabel -> "T(\[Degree]C)", 
    Ticks -> Table[{i, 45 - i}, {i, 15, 31}], 
    LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black, 11}], {Top, Center}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You do realize that's not supposed to work, right?

Comment: @rcollyer Let's write a complain to WRI! :D

Comment: You can also use `ColorData[{"TemperatureMap","Reverse"}]`

Comment: @SimonWoods Thanks! Never used it

Comment: @rcollyer why is that not supposed to work?

Comment: @RiemannZeta run `Options@BarLegend` and note the lack of `Ticks`.

Answer (score 3):

### LegendLayout -> "ReversedRow"

Using `LegendLayout -> "ReversedRow"`, you can reverse both the color scheme and the ticks without having to touch the color scheme or the ticks list. We need to add padding so that the tick labels are visible:

```
bl = BarLegend[{"TemperatureMap", {15, 30}}, 
 LegendLabel -> Style["T(°C)", Bold, 11], 
 LegendMarkerSize -> 300,
 "Ticks" -> Range[15, 31], 
 LegendLayout -> "ReversedRow", 
 Method -> {ImagePadding -> {{0, 0}, {20, 0}}}]
```

[image]

Use `"TickSide" -> Left` and `ImagePadding -> {{0, 0}, {0, 20}}` to get

[image]

Add the option  `"TickLengths" -> -4` to put the ticks outside the frame:

[image]

Use as legend in a `Plot` object:

```
Legended[Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}], Placed[bl, Top]] (* 0r *)
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, PlotLegends -> Placed[Pane @ bl, Top]]
```

[image]